# Java method synchronization improper usage?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose there is the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    synchronized void myMethod1() {
        //code 
    }

    synchronized void myMethod2() {
        //code
    }
}
```

Now suppose `myMethod1()` and `myMethod2()` access distinct data; now if there are two threads, thread A calling only `myMethod1()` and thread B calling only `myMethod2()`.

If thread A is executing `myMethod1()`, will thread B block waiting on `myMethod2()` even if they don't access the same data and there is no reason for this? As far as I know, synchronized methods use the monitor of `this` object for instance methods and that of `MyClass.class` object for static functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in all your suppositions. In the case where no data is in common then there is no reason to synchronize at the method level.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of the situation is correct.

The typical solution is to have separate dedicated [lock objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) for the resources in question.

```
class MyClass {
    private final Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

    void myMethod1() {          
      lock1.lock();

      try {
        //code 
      } finally {
        lock1.unlock();
      }            
    }

    void myMethod2() {
      lock2.lock();

      try {
        //code 
      } finally {
        lock2.unlock();
      }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sychronized` method will lock on the object itself.  So each method will have to wait for the other to finish its access to release the object.  If your methods are truly accessing distinct data you can do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private static Object mLock1 = new Object();
    private static Object mLock2 = new Object();

    void myMethod1() {
        synchronized(mLock1) {
            //code 
        }
    }

    void myMethod2() {
        synchronized(mLock2) {
            //code 
        }
    }
}
```

And you can then access them independently.

edit: You can essentially think of synchronized methods as being equivalent to this:

```
void myMethod1() {
    synchronized(this) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Shown like this it is pretty clear why two synchronized methods block each other because they have to wait for the lock on `this` to free.

Comment: @DuncanJones Oh, I think we posted within ~10 seconds of each other.  edit: not sure what you imply by "suspiciously" either

Comment: @DuncanJones Ah, np. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, declaring both methods as `synchronized` will make them block each other, even if they access different data elements.

To avoid this, you can use a more fine grained locks. E.g.:

```
class MyClass {
    private static final Object lock1 = new Object();
    private static final Object lock2 = new Object();

    void myMethod1() {
        synchronized (lock1) {
            //code 
        }
    }

    void myMethod2() {
        synchronized (lock2) {
            //code 
        }
}
```

Comment: Or a [lock object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use different monitors for `myMethod1` and `myMethod2` as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    Object monitor1 = new Object();
    Object monitor2 = new Object();
    void myMethod1() {
        synchornized(monitor1) {
        //code 
        }
    }

    void myMethod2() {
        synchronized(monitor2) {
        //code
        }
    }
}
```